# Resetting logical Direct-Access Error || RHEL 7.x

Tags: rhel, lvm, hp

We have an error for the LVM resetting device which has been impacting our Linux server during this period.

```
kernel: hpsa 0000:02:00.0: scsi 0:1:0:1: resetting logical Direct-Access HP LOGICAL VOLUME RAID-1(+0) SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=1

kernel: hpsa 0000:02:00.0: device is ready.
```

Below current SCSI disks.

```
[0:0:0:0]    storage HP       P420i            6.68  -
[0:1:0:0]    disk    HP       LOGICAL VOLUME   6.68  /dev/sda
[0:1:0:1]    disk    HP       LOGICAL VOLUME   6.68  /dev/sdb
[1:0:0:0]    tape    HP       Ultrium 4-SCSI   U57D  /dev/st0
[2:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  hp       DVD A  DU8D4SH   MHE4  /dev/sr0
```

Also by checking the disks, we didn't find any HW failure.

```
Smart Array P420i in Slot 0 (Embedded)

Note: Predictive Spare Activation Mode is enabled, physical drives that are in predictive failure state will not be available for use as data or spare drives.

(sn: 00143803620FFA0)

Port Name: 1I

Port Name: 2I

Internal Drive Cage at Port 1I, Box 1, OK

Internal Drive Cage at Port 2I, Box 1, OK array A (SAS, Unused Space: 0 MB)

  logicaldrive 1 (279.4 GB, RAID 1, OK)

  physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 300 GB, OK, spare)
array B (SAS, Unused Space: 0 MB)

  logicaldrive 2 (558.7 GB, RAID 1+0, OK)

  physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:5 (port 2I:box 1:bay 5, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:6 (port 2I:box 1:bay 6, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:7 (port 2I:box 1:bay 7, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:8 (port 2I:box 1:bay 8, SAS, 300 GB, OK, spare)
SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model SRCv8x6G) 380 (WWID: 500143803620FFAF)
```

This error was found only on one of the servers while others not suffering from the same problem.

I am trying to find a way to detect the problem fix as all topics going to a hw faulty while I didn't find any HP HW failures

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with LVM. It's about the logical disk created by the hardware RAID controller. Unfortunately HP had chosen a name that sounds similar to LVM terminology.

The second log message ("device is ready") indicates the error state was automatically cleared.

Your hardware RAID controller is a HP(E) Smart Array P420i. It appears to have firmware version 6.68 which has several known issues that have been fixed in later firmware versions:

https://support.hpe.com/connect/s/softwaredetails?language=en_US&softwareId=MTX_42b6aa58956a438aa85bd73d0f&tab=revisionHistory

The latest firmware version is 8.32 from November 2017, [downloadable here](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/swd/detail?swItemId=MTX_42b6aa58956a438aa85bd73d0f#tab3). The main fixed issue in the latest version is described as:

> System can potentially stop responding with no lockup code due to livelock condition where the RAID Stack thread is polling a queue for a completion to be returned by the base code firmware

which seems like it might well be the issue you're seeing. So updating the RAID controller firmware to the latest available version might fix the root cause. [Read the installation instructions](https://support.hpe.com/connect/s/softwaredetails?language=en_US&softwareId=MTX_42b6aa58956a438aa85bd73d0f&tab=Installation+Instructions) before starting the update.

When a disk controller stops responding, the Linux kernel will automatically attempt to reset it first, regardless of controller type... and in your case, it seems to have successfully unjammed the RAID controller and prevented the system from crashing. In other words, it was a valid workaround; however, relying on that is obviously not ideal, especially if the condition happens again and again.

---

Note that HPE says the P420i is a Retired Product, i.e. no longer manufactured and sold as new. Your current firmware version was released in October 2015, so the RAID controller seems to be about 8 years old now. Large enterprises would seriously consider retiring any critical x86 servers of that age just on the basis of aging, as vendor support for such old servers becomes prohibitively expensive and/or not as effective as with current hardware, as the timely availability of spare parts becomes difficult.

If you have a large number of similar servers you can cannibalize for spare parts, you might be able to deal with failures on your own. Otherwise, I hope you have good backups and a workable plan on what to do **when** (not **if**) some component of your server eventually fails.